# Regex to replace multiple patterns with single not working

Tags: sql, regex, hana

I am working on replacing multiple occurance of string 0000 with single random number in HANA SQL

I have used these patterns

1. `'(\w+)\s+\1'`
2. `'([0000 ]+) \1'`

but all occurrences are replaced except the last occurrence of the pattern

```
SELECT REPLACE_REGEXPR('(\w+)\s+\1' IN '0000 0000 0000' WITH ROUND(RAND()*1000) OCCURRENCE ALL) AS a2
FROM DUMMY;
```

Current output is

```
RANDOM 0000
```

expected output is

```
RANDOM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(\d+)(?:\s+\1)+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZvWR54/1)

You need `\d` to match digits (if you need to match letters and `_` keep on using `\w`).
Also, to match 1 or more repetitions of a sequence of patterns you need `(?:....)+`, a `+` quantified non-capturing group.

**Pattern details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?:\s+\1)+` - 1+ repetitions of 1+ whitespaces and the same value as captured in Group 1
- `\b` - word boundary

[Regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(%5Cd%2B)(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5C1)%2B%5Cb):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
((0000) +)+(0000)
```

[Look Here](https://regex101.com/r/SwXHB8/1)

And if it's OK to use any digit and more \ less times then 4:

```
(\d+ +)+\d+
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Sea Sharp!
Actual string is in this example. Could you please look into it?
I am trying to replace numbers but not the text :) [link](https://regex101.com/r/6KMpeq/1/)

Comment: @saurabhC. Do you want to replace exactly 4 zero's?

Comment: @saurabhC. Look at the answer now.